# AspectJ: target vs signature pattern to select methods on a class

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Whats the difference between these two pointcuts?  When should I use one construction over the other?

```
pointcut first_pointcut(): target(MyClass) && call(void myMethod(..))
pointcut second_pointcut(): call(void MyClass.myMethod(..))
```

My confusion began when reading the [AspectJ Programming Guide](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/index.html).   Some examples in the guide will restrict pointcut applications to specific classes by using signature patterns like this:

```
call(public * Figure.* (..))
```

which "picks out each call to Figure's public methods."  Other examples use target to restrict the pointcut application to certain classes, like this:

```
pointcut setter(): target(Point) &&
               (call(void setX(int)) ||
                call(void setY(int)));
```

which "picks out each call to setX(int) or setY(int) when called on an instance of Point."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target expects an *instance* of the class specified, while call itself has no such restriction. That means the pointcut with just call(..) can catch static method executions as well, while one with a target(Class) can not. It only catches methods executed on an object of the specified class (hence the name 'target').